# Express JS reject requests that aren't GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I reject requests in Express JS that aren't `GET` requests (to be precise I want to allow `GET` and `OPTIONS` for `CORS`). Express, by default responds with an error page. For instance if i `POST` `http://127.0.0.1:3005/health`, express, by default, responds with

> Cannot POST /health

But I want to actually reject the request entirely. The reason for this is security. Our devops say there are massive `POST` requests on any of our urls where people try to penetrate the service. Also rejecting those requests may improve server load.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reject"? I mean, if returning an error is not a rejection, what is?

Answer (score 1):

Express actually does almost nothing by default. So the easiest way to ignore posts is do do nothing. Express is already ignoring posts for you and sending an error.

However if you have plugins that are inspecting all headers etc you could also explicitly reject POST requests by putting following above all other handlers in your root script (index.js , app.js whatever you called it)

```
app.post('*', function(req, res){
   res.status(403).end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** and specify only **GET** / **OPTIONS** methods as available

For some details - please read:

- https://staticapps.org/articles/cross-domain-requests-with-cors/ - A Common Example
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ - Preflight Request